# Percentage Calculator using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following values

```
x = 7.81;
y = 178.32;
z = (x/y)*100;
```

The percentage must be `4%` for the above result. How can I calculate the percentage using JavaScript?

Comment: What you have should work (if you lowercase `x` first), it outputs 4.37...  As well you should make those local variables (put `var ` before the variable name) unless you have a valid reason not to. What problem did you have with it?  If you just want 4 without the decimals, you can use `Math.round(z)`.

Answer (score 6):

You pretty much have valid Javascript there, with the exception of the mixed case X (Javascript is case sensitive)

```
var x, y, z;

x=7.81;
y=178.32;
z=(x/y)*100;

console.log( z );
```

To get the result to two decimal places (2DP) you can use [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
console.log( z.toFixed(2) );
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var x = 7.81;
var y = 178.32;

var z = (x/y)*100;
```

z stores your percentage then.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're struggling with rounding:

```
var x = 7.81;
var y = 178.32;

alert( Math.round(x / y * 100) + '%' ); // 4%
```

Comment: Lemme see, I have a few spare `$`s around here somewhere…

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var a = 7.81;
var b = 178.32;
var c = a/b;

var result = c*100;

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x,y,z;
x = 7.81;
y = 178.32;

z = (Number(x)/Number(y)) * 100;

console.log(z);
  (or)
alert(z);
```

Comment: because it may convert even the string into number

Comment: @Ashwin—The `/` and `*` operators do that anyway. The brackets around the division are also redundant (as in completely unnecessary).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that you can use in different ways like below

```
function percentage(x, y)
{
    return (x / y) * 100;
}


console.log(percentage(7.81, 178.32) + '%');
console.log(percentage(7.81, 178.32).toFixed(2) + '%'); // rounded to 2 decimal places
console.log(percentage(7.81, 178.32).toFixed(0) + '%'); // rounded to integer
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/wR8jk/) for demo